# All pyramiding trades close at the same time

Tags: pine-script, trading, back-testing, pine-script-v5

I have TP and SL based on ATR value at entry moment. I have pyramiding option turned on, but then, all open at specific time trades (that are in the same direction: long or short) close at the same moment, all together. How to make every trade independent and how to make every trade being closed on a set at entry TP or SL.

Ps. TP = 2ATR, SL = 1ATR

Ps 2. Pine script version5

Similar problem here: [Pyramiding trades with independent take profit (Pinescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866365/pyramiding-trades-with-independent-take-profit-pinescript)

My code for Long trades:

```
ATR = ta.atr(14)

if EntryLongCondiction1 and EntryLongCondiction2
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

lastLongEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

var float LongProfit = na
var float LongStop = na

if (strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)
    LongProfit := lastLongEntryPrice + (ATR * 2)
    LongStop := lastLongEntryPrice - (ATR * 1)

strategy.exit("Long", stop=LongStop, limit=LongProfit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all the entry and exit conditions are the same name in `"Long"`, the entry might not be in the same place, but exit will. ATR will hit and trigger the exit condition with all names with `"Long"` order. If you got a different condition or fixed tp/sl ratio, try naming it like `Long 1`, `Long2`, etc.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Different id for entries, exits or both?

Comment: yup,diffrent id ,but if the condition is same thats useless...

Comment: Yes, condotions are same. So how I can do that? I just want to have multiple trades.